# Mixed Nash Equilibria and Negative Probability

Tags: probability, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am currently attempting to look for mixed equilibria in this payoff matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}(\boldsymbol{1},1) & (\boldsymbol5,2) & (\boldsymbol0,0) \\(\boldsymbol2,5) & (\boldsymbol3,3) & (\boldsymbol1,0) \\ (\boldsymbol0,0) & (\boldsymbol0,1) & (\boldsymbol2,2) \end{bmatrix}$

(You can call the row player Player 1 for simplicity and Player 2 the column player. I put the payoffs for player 1 in bold).

Now, I did find three pure NE's (that is to say (2,5), (5,2) and (2,2)), as well as a few mixed equilibria for the various subgames. I can't, however, find a mixed equilibrium for the entire game (in particular, if I assign probability $p_1$ to the first column, it turns out to be $-\frac{1}{9}$ in a linear system of equations.)

How am I supposed to interpret that negative probability? I know this game is supposed to have an odd number of Nash equilibria, but the I obtain an even number.

Besides what I wrote in the original problem, I also found the following mixed equilibria in the subgames. I am labeling the column player's actions l, c, and r (from left to right) and the row player plays u, m, d from the top down. So we have:

-(u, m) played with probability 2/3 and 1/3; and (l,c) played with probability 2/3 and 1/3

-(m,d) played with probability 2/7 and 5/7 ; and (l,r) played with probability 1/3 and 2/3

-(m,d) played with probability 1/4 and 3/4 ; and (c,r) played with probability 1/4 and 3/4

-(u,d) played with probability 2/3 and 1/3 ; and (l,r) played with probability 2/3 and 1/3

-(u,d) played with probability 1/3 and 2/3; and (c,r) played with probability 2/7 and 5/7

Answer (score 1):

Negative probability is meaningless. Getting a negative probability in your calculation simply means that there is no mixed strategy Nash equilibrium in which either player randomizes over all three of their pure strategies.

---

Of all the mixed strategy profiles you listed, only the first and third ones are MSNEs. Note that the indifference condition is only a necessary condition, not a sufficient one. You need to ensure that the mixed strategies leading to indifference are indeed *best responses*.

For example, in your second profile, when Player 1 plays $\frac27m+\frac57d$, it is true that Player 2 is indifferent between $l$ and $r$ (payoff is $\frac{10}7$), but choosing $c$ leads to a higher payoff ($\frac{11}7>\frac{10}7$). So the best response to $\frac27m+\frac57d$ is the pure strategy $c$ as opposed to $\frac13l+\frac23r$. The other non-MSNE profiles have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for that. Could you please help me identify all the mixed equilibria then? Because if we include the pure ones I am left with an even number of those.

Comment: @Anonymous instead of me giving you the answer, why don't you show what you've done and ask for verification?

Comment: I added them to the main problem now.

Comment: @Anonymous: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again for explaining this to me.