# Mixed strategy Nash equilibrium - what dose a negative probability mean?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider the game table below for a zero-sum game with two players, a row player (who wants to maximize the payoff), and a column player (who wants to minimize the payoff). I am looking for a mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium. If row player selects row i with probability pi, finding a mixed strategy that makes column player indifference across his actions results in negative p2. Since the row 2 is not dominated by other rows, how should I interpret the negative probability? The same thing happens to the column player.

\begin{bmatrix}1.5197&1.6569&1.8113\\1.1784&0.4629&2.0625\\1.9041&1.1683&1.0211\end{bmatrix}

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679599/.

Answer (score 1):

Indifference only holds among the actions for which the strategy has non-integer probability. If the probability is $0$ or $1$, the player need not be indifferent between this action and other actions: She may want to reduce (or increase) the weight of the action, but she can’t, since it’s already $0$ (or $1$).

Thus, by assuming indifference for all actions, you assumed that all probabilities are non-integers. That this yields a negative probability proves by contradiction that there is no Nash equilibrium that satisfies this assumption. You can now try subsets of the actions and set the probabilities for the remaining actions to $0$. Since a mixed Nash equilibrium is guaranteed to exist, you should find some subset of the actions such that assuming indifference among them and $0$ probability for the remaining actions yields non-negative probabilities. Then to show that this is actually an equilibrium, you should check that the actions with zero probability are not better responses to the other player’s strategy than the ones with non-zero probability.

Comment: Thanks, it works. To the best of my knowledge, setting the probability of an action to 0 means that action is dominated by other actions. I don't see this interpretation works here. Then how should discuss this situation in general? Is it enough to say since there is no NE while there should be, then we have to ignore some actions until an NE appears?

Comment: @Javidit: Those are two different things. $A$ being dominated by $B$ means that $A$ is worse than $B$ *independent of the other player's strategy*. Here the actions with zero probability are worse responses to the other player's equilibrium strategy than the actions with non-zero probabilities; they might be better responses to other strategies, so they need not be dominated. Nevertheless, since the strategies in equilibrium are by definition best responses, the probabilities for actions that are not best responses are necessarily zero – that doesn't mean we're "ignoring" them.

Comment: @Javidit: To put it differently: Eliminating dominated actions is a special case of what you're doing here. Here you're discarding actions that are not best responses to a certain strategy. You can only do this in the context of a certain strategy for the opponent. In the case of domination, you can discard actions *a priori* because you know they can never be best responses, regardless of the opponent's strategy, so you don't have to wait until you have a specific strategy before discarding them.